# Iterating through all possible Letter combinations

Tags: c, loops, cs50, crypt

Trying to crack password using brute force but program does not seem to realize when it found the password.

So I tried writing a little program to crack passwords using brute force.
basically I iterate rhough all letter combinations using nested for loops (The passwords needn't be longer than 4 letters), then I use crypt on the password with a given salt (assuming the salt is fixed) to check whether I cracked the password (I have access to the crypted passwords). Now I had the code output what it generates and it looks like it does iterate through all lowercase variants. But somehow it never find the password.

Now I have created the crypted version myself so I know the password is 4 Letters long, that’s not the problem and the program does seems to iterate through all possibilities, I think, so what could be the problem ? Is the if condition wrong ?

Now I guess this is not the most elegant solution for the problem but I think the general Idea is right. But if there is a problem with that nested for loop approach I'd be happy to know that to :).

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
 #include <unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {

if(argc < 2) {
printf("Please enter a password to crack! \n");
return 1;
}


char s[4] = "";



for(int i = 0; i <=27; i++) {

    if(i == 0)
    s[0] = 0;
    else
    s[0] =  i - 1 + 'a';

    if(strcmp(crypt(s, "50"), argv[1]) == 0) {

    break; }
        for(int j = 0; j <=26; j++) {
            if(j == 0)
            s[1] = 0;
            else
        s[1] = (j - 1 + 'a');

        if(strcmp(crypt(s, "50"), argv[1]) == 0)
        break;
            for(int k = 0; k <= 26; k++) {
                if(k == 0)
                s[2] = 0;

                s[2] =  (k - 1 + 'a');


            if(strcmp(crypt(s, "50"), argv[1]) == 0)
            break;
                for(int l = 0; l <= 26; l++) {
                    printf("%s \n", s);
                    if(l == 0)
                    s[3] = 0;
                    else
                    s[3] =  (l - 1 + 'a');



                    if(strcmp(crypt(s, "50"), argv[1]) == 0)
                    break;
                }

            }
        }


}

if (strcmp(crypt(s, "50"), argv[1]) != 0)
printf("Password not found");
else
printf("%s \n", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `char s[4]` fails to leave room for a null character terminator when the array has four non-null characters, resulting in behavior not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

C strings are null terminated, that means, that a string in C is basically an array of bytes/characters (like the one you initialize: `char s[4] = "";`) with the last byte set to 0.

`strcmp` goes through two strings(byte arrays) and compares them one by one until it finds a different character or until both strings end, i.e. the currently compared byte is a 0 for both strings. When you initialize your char array `s` to be 4 bytes, and write 4 non-null bytes into it, `strcmp` will continue comparing bytes after the end of the array, because it did not hit the end of a string. This can also crash your program or lead to security vulnerabilities, because you continue reading into memory, that you are not supposed to. To get around this, properly terminate your input strings with a null byte and use the `strncmp` function when possible, which takes an additional parameter, indicating how many characters it should compare at most.

As you correctly identified, the nested loop approach is not the most elegant solution, because you are repeating yourself over and over and the resulting code is very rigid and can only compare up to 4 character passwords. It would be cleaner to have an outer for loop to loop through the possible passwords lengths and then call a function which checks all possible passwords of a certain length (using two nested loops).

If you are just looking to bruteforce some passwords and not actually want to program it yourself, you will probably be better of using some professional tool like https://hashcat.net/hashcat/.